# Oracle query to find if an account has been negative for some days

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which has balance for accounts on a daily basis. Need to know how I can find all the accounts that have been negative for more than certain no.of days.

Sample data-

```
Accountid Date         Balance 
1000      01/01/2020   -1.00
1000      01/02/2020   -1.00
1000      01/03/2020   -1.00
1001      01/01/2020   -20.00
1001      01/02/2020   -20.00
1003      01/01/2020    15.00
1003      01/02/2020    16.00
```

I need to query all the accounts that have been negative for more than 2 days

Comment: Are you looking for all accounts that have been negative for consecutive days or just overall?

Comment: If consecutive, do they have to be the most recent days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to consider only consecutive days then:

```sql
SELECT AccountId
FROM   (
  SELECT Accountid, DateTime, Balance,
         SUM( has_changed_sign )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY AccountId ORDER BY DateTime )
           AS grp
  FROM   (
    SELECT Accountid, DateTime, Balance,
           CASE
           WHEN SIGN( balance )
                = LAG( SIGN( Balance ) )
                    OVER ( PARTITION BY AccountId ORDER BY DateTime )
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1
           END AS has_changed_sign
    FROM   table_name t
  )
  WHERE Balance < 0
)
GROUP BY AccountID, grp
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

So, for the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Accountid, DateTime, Balance ) AS 
SELECT 1000, DATE '2020-01-01',  -1.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- 3 consecutive -ve days
SELECT 1000, DATE '2020-01-02',  -1.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1000, DATE '2020-01-03',  -1.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1000, DATE '2020-01-04',  +1.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1001, DATE '2020-01-01', -20.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- Only 2 negative
SELECT 1001, DATE '2020-01-02', -20.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1001, DATE '2020-01-03', +20.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1001, DATE '2020-01-04', +20.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, DATE '2020-01-01',  -1.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- 3 negative days but
SELECT 1002, DATE '2020-01-02',  -1.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- only 2 consecutive
SELECT 1002, DATE '2020-01-03',  +1.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, DATE '2020-01-04',  -1.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1003, DATE '2020-01-01', +15.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL -- All positive
SELECT 1003, DATE '2020-01-02', +16.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1003, DATE '2020-01-03', +17.00 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1003, DATE '2020-01-04', +18.00 FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> | ACCOUNTID |
> | --------: |
> |      1000 |
> ```

If you only want more than 2 days then you could simply use `LAG`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       AccountID
FROM (
  SELECT AccountID,
         balance,
         LAG( balance, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY DateTime )
           AS balance_1_day_ago,
         LAG( balance, 2 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY DateTime )
           AS balance_2_days_ago
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  balance < 0
AND    balance_1_day_ago < 0
AND    balance_2_days_ago < 0;
```

But that isn't going to scale well if you want to check over a larger period as the query is quickly going to become very large.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8f4115a17954c43d5c8eada719d2622f)*

Answer (score 2):

You could query the days with negative balances, group by the account ID and then count how many rows you got in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT   AccountID
FROM     mytable
WHERE    balance < 0
GROUP BY AccountID
HAVING   COUNT(*) >= 2
```

Comment: would it consider consecutive days

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Select accountid, count(date) from table
Where balance < 0
Group by accountid
Having count(date) >2

Answer (score 1):

Use a filter in a `WHERE` clause to get only the negative balances, then group by the account ID and in a `HAVING` clause check for the count of distinct days being greater than your limit of days.

```
SELECT accountid
       FROM elbat
       WHERE balance < 0
       GROUP BY accountid
       HAVING count(DISTINCT date) > 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all columns then use partition by. The below solution would take count of date's order too

```
    Select Accountid, Date,  Balance, 
    row_number() over (Partition by 
     Accountid order by Date) 
   rn from table
   Where balance<0 and rn>2 ;
```

Comment: would it consider consecutive days? If the account is negative for one day and not the other, it shouldnt appear in the resultset

Comment: Did u try to run the above query?